# How can I interrupt a Watir script while keeping connectivity to the browser?

Tags: ruby, exception, watir, interrupt

I have a script that uses Watir webdriver. However, it takes a long time and I need to stop it occasionally. I'd like to be able to interrupt it and handle the interrupt by performing a few tasks, such as logging out of the website I am on. Then, it would need a way to resume the process. I am using ruby, and, so far, I have tried rescue Interrupt => e as well as Signal.trap("TSTP") do |signo| {...}. In both of these, I cannot perform any closing operations on the browser because it seems that I have lost connection to it. Is there any way I can pause the script by keyboard and perform some exit operations on the Watir browser?

```
Signal.trap("TSTP") do |signo|
    browser.link(:text=> "Logout").click
    ap "Paused. Press <enter> to continue."
    $stdin.gets
    Process.kill("STOP", Process.pid)
end
```

After stopping gives me `` ^Z/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout) ``.

Comment: can you show the relevant part of your script?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]".